# Removing extra space between the word and apostrophe

Tags: python, string, text-mining

I have a list of strings which contain contraction from of verbs.
My list is something like this:

```
["What 's your name?", "Isn 't it beautiful?",...]
```

I want to remove the space between the word and the apostrophe, so the new list would be:

```
["What's your name?", "Isn't it beautiful?",...]
```

I used `replace()`but the list contains 5500 strings and there are different forms of contractions in it. The following code just replaces one form of contraction.

```
s = s.replace("'s","is")
```

What should I do to remove the extra space between the word and the apostrophe?

Comment: What do you mean, the list is too long?

Comment: Can you show us an example of how you have used `replace` and what the problem was?

Comment: @aryamccarthy I added more explanations.

Comment: @Geotob Added more explanations.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. At the start, you say you want to replace `what 's` with `what's`, then you give code which would replace it with `whatis`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z])\s+(?=[a-z]*'\s*[a-z])
```

You can try this:

https://regex101.com/r/18GHqw/1

```
import re

regex = r"(?<=[a-zA-Z])\s+(?=[a-z]*'\s*[a-z])"

test_str = ("'What 's your name?','Isn 't it beautiful?'\n\n"
"Jesus ' cross\"\n"
"do n't\"\n"
"sdsda   sdsd'  sdsd")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use `ur""` to prefix the regex and `u""` to prefix the test string and substitution.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
l = ["What 's your name?", "Isn 't it beautiful"]
lNew = [i.replace(" '","'") for i in l]
```

This gives:

```
lNew = ["What's your name?", "Isn't it beautiful"]
```

It seems like you're using the same symbol for apostrophe and the strings, but I'm sure in your program they are different.

Does this help?

Comment: Thank, but the is other problem, too. There are some words like "Jesus ' cross" or "do n't" !! I don't know what to do !

Comment: It should work for the "Jesus ` cross" example (since that matches the expression "  `". For "do n`t" that is rather strange - do you mind if I ask where the data is from? Perhaps there is a preprocessing step that can avoid this.

Comment: @Cyber what should be the result of `Jesus ' cross` or `do n't`

Comment: I would guess "Jesus' cross" and "don't" (which could later be changed to "do not").

Comment: @vks It should be `Jesus' cross` and `don't`

Comment: @Cyber can you test your data against https://regex101.com/r/oHcYBE/1 if this works i can post it as answer

Comment: @vks Sorry, I'm new to python. I don't know how to use RE.

Comment: @SiHa Yes I know, but to distinguish apostrophes from the single-quote used to define a string I used a back-tick.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with regular expression in this way.(This will help you in more no. of spaces, but not for `do n ot`s as you mentioned in the comments.)

`import re
s = ["What 's your name?","Isn 't it beautiful?"]
s = [re.sub(r'\s+\'', "'", i) for i in s]`

Output will be 
`>>> s
["What's your name?", "Isn't it beautiful?"]`